# How to remove text auto save in html input

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade

How to remove this text like history in my input can anyone teach me how to remove this i'm using laravel 5.5 blade template please see image below.

[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiJ7h.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable `autocomplete`

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the `autocomplete="off"` attribute to your `input`.